# Java checkbox with AND operator

Tags: java

Please, I want to use the AND operator with checkbox in creating different options.

```
if (chkd.isSelected()){
   lbl.setText("hello");
} 
 else if (chkd.isSelected() && chkm.isSelected()){
   lbl.setText("cool");
}
```

Please, what's the best approach to do this. I am using Eclipse for Java.

Answer (score 0):

As written, assuming `chkd` and `chkm` are defined won't work because if the `if` statement is true, the `else if` won't execute.

Try this instead:

```
if (chkd.isSelected()) {
    if (chkm.isSelected()) {
        lbl.setText("cool");
    } else {
        lbl.setText("hello");
    }
}
```

What's happening is we're checking `chkd` is true, we then check to see if `chkm` is true we're `cool`, otherwise, we're `hello`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can turn around your if statement.

So checking first for the (a && b) Statement will give you the cool value. If the && is not true, your other Statement (hello) will be displayed.

```
    if (chkd.isSelected() && chkm.isSelected()) { 
        lbl.setText("cool"); 
    } else if {
        lbl.setText("hello"); 
    }
```